# iOS prevent rotation in certain views

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a viewcontroller and its view that support only landscape in iPad.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    return NO;
else
    return YES;

}
```

But I have a view with a movie player that needs to be in portrait only.  So in this view I do this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    return YES;
else
    return NO;
}
```

My problem is that if I, in the first viewcontroller set portrait to NO, then my second view controller will never rotate to portrait.  The secondviewcontroller is added as a subview of the first.  How can I get view 1 to not rotate to portrait, but get view 2 to not rotate to landscape.  This app is for demo purposes so really i'm just looking for the technical answer on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible when adding as a subview. Try pushing the new view onto an invisible UINavigationController stack to accomplish your goal. This will work when going from the first view to the second, but it is very tricky to get the first view to rotate *back* to its original position when the 2nd vc is popped because apple does not want you doing this. Here's a very very hacky trick to force it back on pop:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {   
    UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:c animated:NO];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [c release];    
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but since we're already talking about hacky solutions, I believe you can set the rotation of the device directly with -[UIScreen setStatusBarOrientation:animated:].  I've never tried it, and there's some scary warnings in the documentation, so it might not be the best idea...

Comment: True... I've read about that manner also. But as you stated, this is a demo so hacks may work for now ;)

Comment: Thanks. And setStatusBarOrientation and [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:] can't even override the shouldAutoRotate properties

Answer (score 0):

When I have encountered this problem in the past, I have done this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   if(mayRotate){
      return YES;
   }else{
      return NO;
   }
}
```

I think there's a little more to it, but you should have the idea.