# Xcode iphone orientation support for certain views

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to support all orientations for all views except for the main view controller. I can't seem to find a way to do that.

I can either support orientation for all views or no views throughout the app. How do you support orientations for certain views throughout the app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630359/ios-6-how-do-i-restrict-some-views-to-portrait-and-allow-others-to-rotate/13194720#13194720

Comment: No, I am not sure how to subclass the top most controller. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: I get "viewController does not declare selector last object"

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet worked with an app that needed to act that way you describe, but here is what the Apple Documentation suggests when you need to control orientation support:

> Dynamically Controlling Whether Rotation Occurs
>
> Sometimes you may want to dynamically disable automatic rotation. For
>   example, you might do this when you want to suppress rotation
>   completely for a short period of time. You must temporarily disable
>   orientation changes you want to manually control the position of the
>   status bar (such as when you call the
>   setStatusBarOrientation:animated: method).
>
> **> If you want to temporarily disable automatic rotation, avoid
>   manipulating the orientation masks to do this. Instead, override the
>   shouldAutorotate method on the topmost view controller. This method is
>   called before performing any autorotation. If it returns NO, then the
>   rotation is suppressed.**

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW1

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the top most controller .
For example you have a navigation controller  as the top most controller then you just need to
subclass `UINavigationController` and write the following line of code in .m file of the subclass

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

Now overwrite the method `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate` for each of the controllers in your project.
Return `TRUE` for those controller for which you need to do rotation and Return `FALSE` for those controller for which you dont need to do rotation .

Cheers!!!!!

Comment: Can you please provide an example with this implemented? I can't seem to get it to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: First of all above piece of code will work after ios 5.0 as from 5.0 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate  has come. I can send you the helper subclass of navigation controller that i have used in my application.