# How to set Portrait mode when it's in landscape?

Tags: iphone, interface, rotation, landscape, portrait

I am making an application which supports portrait, landscape left, landscape right interface orientiations. However in my application, there are some view controllers for which I want to have only portrait. It means that, when you rotate this view controller, no changing should happen. I try to describe in this image. [image](http://i1315.photobucket.com/albums/t595/chuyenmuathi/Untitled_zps33a26523.png)

Please help me, It's important to my project :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        return YES; 
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: I tried. I only need insert your code to my project? It doesn't work. I am using iOS 6

Comment: I make a new project to test your code. Can you see project in here: [Link download project](https://app.box.com/s/zshofy86gx7ovxjirek1). It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through my answer in the following link.

[Xcode iphone orientation support for certain views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446633/xcode-iphone-orientation-support-for-certain-views/13451814#13451814)

I think it would help you..

Comment: Can you help me fix my project and send it to me. I make a new project to test your code. Can you see project in here: [Link down project] (https://app.box.com/files/0/f/0/1/f_10048079157)  THank you :(