# interface orientation in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I have to make some changes in an existing app. That app was last update in June when iOS6.0 was not launched. I am wondering how the orientation works properly on the devices running with iOS6.0?? As that build contains deprecated methods of oreintation?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

This method doesnt get called in iOS6.0 then how that app  in app store is working fine in iOS6 devices? Additionally if i run this app from xcode using its code, then it doesnt support orientation for iOS6. Now my client is saying app on app store is working fine with orientation in all the devices and the new build is not supporting orientation. I know I can fix this issue by using new methods for orientation

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate
```

but just curious to know how older app is working fine on iOS6 devices using deprecated methods when those method are not even getting called in when i run it using xcode.

Comment: There are some answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13809409/581994), though it's not the complete answer, by far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older applications were compiled using iOS 5.x SDK, that's why they can run fine on iOS 6, the problem occurs when you compile non iOS 6 compliant code with iOS 6.x SDK.

Comment: Well, it's not "non iOS 6 optimised" code that's the problem, it's that they completely changed the rules.

Comment: maybe "compliant" is a better word :)

Comment: "Compliant" is how Apple likes their customers.

Comment: You sound quite irritated by Apple.