# iOS - support Rotations for specific ViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I have a hierarchy of 3 views

I've created a subclass for my NavigationViewController, and setup a property `Landscape` which determines whether each viewController can support different orientations.

This property is set in the `ViewWillAppear` of each View controller: this works perfectly. Controller 1 and 2 are portrait only, and controller 3 supports both portrait and landscape orientations.

**The issue arrises when I'm going back `popping` controller 3 to go back to controller 2 
IF i'm in controller 3 in landscape orientation, and I click the back button, my Controller 2 is presented to me in Landscape orientation : (controller 2 does not support Landscape)**

Then i have to rotate the device for the orientation to fix itself . . . .

code in Navigation Controller
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
       return YES;
    }

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   if (LandscapeOK) {
       // for iPhone, you could also return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
   } else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Code at Each ViewControllers `ViewWillAppear` Method

```
[(NavigationViewController *)[self navigationController] setLandscape:YES];
```

I have my code set up almost exactly the same way as this question: the same problem as well. Question was posted a year or so back but yet no appropriate solution - while going through the answers listed

[iOS 6: How do I restrict some views to portrait and allow others to rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630359/ios-6-how-do-i-restrict-some-views-to-portrait-and-allow-others-to-rotate/13090766#13090766)

Comment: From 'Hierarchy', do you mean, you have one parent 'NavigationViewController' with property 'Landscape' on it, while all the other controllers (1, 2, & 3) derive from it?

Comment: yes - there is a button in each VC that leads to the next 1 -> 2 -> 3

Answer (score 0):

Given 
1. the reply you have given to my comment, 
2. you have tried the solution suggested below:

[iOS 6: How do I restrict some views to portrait and allow others to rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630359/ios-6-how-do-i-restrict-some-views-to-portrait-and-allow-others-to-rotate/13090766#13090766)

what I perceive, you have same/common property LandscapeOK accessible across all controllers.

I suggest you to debug and check value of LandscapeOK inside supportedInterfaceOrientations, when you naviagte back to controller 2 from Controller 3.