# iOS NSInvalidArgumentException: Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to follow the code in this example: [iOS 6: How do I restrict some views to portrait and allow others to rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630359/ios-6-how-do-i-restrict-some-views-to-portrait-and-allow-others-to-rotate)

I created a subclass of UINavigationController called **customNavigationController**:

**customNavigationController.m**

```
@implementation CustomNavigationController
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.landscapeOK) {
        NSLog(@"all orientation ok");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    NSLog(@"only portrait orientation");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

**CustomNavigationController.h**

```
@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController

@property (nonatomic) BOOL landscapeOK;

@end
```

Then in my app, I try setting the landscapeOK property in **viewWillAppear**:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [(CustomNavigationController*)[self navigationController] setLandscapeOK:NO];
}
```

When I run `[(CustomNavigationController*)[self navigationController] setLandscapeOK:NO];` I get the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setLandscapeOK:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10091ee00'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to actually create a `CustomNavigationController` instead of a `UINavigationController` where you are creating it, you can't just cast something and have it magically change types.

Comment: @dan can you explain how that would look different than what I've done?

Comment: That would depend on where you are creating it. If you create it in the storyboard then you should select the navigation controller and set a custom class in the identity inspector. If you create it in code then change `[UINavigationController alloc]` to `[CustomNavigationController alloc]`

Comment: @dan thanks, I was missing that critical element!  Adding a custom class to my storyboard fixed the problem.  If add this as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the custom class in the identity inspector for your navigation controller in your storyboard to `CustomNavigationController`.